# Changing contract property to public increases gas costs

Tags: solidity, gas, testing, gas-limit, ganache-cli

I am following kind of an outdated tutorial and trying to adapt it to the more recent changes in Solidity and other packages. Following one of my changes, I am running into a problem that I can't find an answer to.

The relevant part of my contract looks like this:

```
contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address payable recipient;
        bool complete;
        mapping (address => bool) approvals;
        uint approvalCount;
    }
    address public manager;
    uint numRequests;
    mapping (uint => Request) requests;
    
    
    modifier restrictedToManager() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
    
    constructor(uint minimum, address creator) {
        manager = creator;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }
    
    function createRequest(string calldata description, uint value, address payable recipient) public restrictedToManager {
        // get last index of requests from storage
       Request storage newRequest = requests[numRequests];
       // increase requests counter
       numRequests ++;
       // add information about new request
       newRequest.description = description;
       newRequest.value = value;
       newRequest.recipient = recipient;
       newRequest.approvalCount = 0;
    }
```

Now I am testing the contract locally using the ganache provider. In one of the tests, I want to call the `createRequest` method and then check if the request has been created. With the code I pasted above, this does not work because the property `requests` has not been set public so I can't run the getter function.

However, once I change that line to `mapping (uint => Request) public requests` and try to test again, the transaction immediately runs out of gas when running the beforeEach hook for the first time, even with a limit of 1.000.000

To be clear, I use the beforeEach hook to deploy the contract.

How can it be that this simple change results in such a big change in gas fees?

Edit:

Find below a snippet of the beforeEach hook inside of my Campaign.test.js
This is where the transaction runs out of gas.

The factory contract is a higher level contract that handles deployments of the campaign contract

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  // get accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  // deploy factory contract
  factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(factoryInterface)
    .deploy({ data: factoryBytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });

  // create campaign from factory contract
  await factory.methods
    .createCampaign("100")
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });

  // assign first element out of the response array to campaignAddress
  [campaignAddress] = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();
  // get javascript represenation of the deployed campaign contract
  campaign = await new web3.eth.Contract(
    campaignInterface,
    campaignAddress // add address as second argument to get already deployed contract
  );
});
```

call to requests getter method

```
it("allows a manager to make a payment request", async () => {
    await campaign.methods
      .createRequest("Test description", "1000", accounts[1])
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
    const request = await campaign.methods.requests(0).call();
    assert.strictEqual("Test description", request.description);
  });
```

I do get the code to work if I simply increase the gas to 3.000.000. I am primarily interested in where the increase in gas fees is coming from instead of how to make the code work

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful if you could add a code snippet with the test you're running too. Also, are you using Truffle? If you could update the question with these, that would be great!

Comment: Sure, check the edit. I am not using Truffle for testing, I'm using mocha

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to `requests` in the tests, could you put in the call to `requests` too?

Comment: according to the output thats not even the issues' source but i added it

Comment: ah! What is the issue's source according to the output?

Comment: ran out of gas while running the beforeEach hook for the first test

Answer (score 0):

I deployed the contract in remix with different solc versions.

| Solc | Private | Public |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.8.2 | 439,788 | 609,500 |
| 0.7.6 | 312,372 | 440,476 |
| 0.6.12 | 308,678 | 436,781 |

There's a notable increment 160k in 0.8, but in previous version was similar 140k.

Since requests returns a structure making it public requires the serialization of the structure that doesn't exists when it is private.

Another important contributor to gas increment is the use of string, replacing it with bytes32 may work in some cases.